# In polyglossia, how can I change the English font in a Hebrew document

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

I want to use polyglossia to write a Hebrew document with some English. The definition of the english font families only applies to English text included within Hebrew text (the word Corona), but not to standalone English text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Palatino Linotype}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Lucida Sans}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{Lucida Sans Typewriter}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{LTR}
\selectlanguage{english}
\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}\\
\textsf{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}\\
\texttt{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}\\
\end{LTR}
\begin{RTL}
לצערי ההרצאה בוטלה בגלל ה-
\textenglish{Corona}.
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the 'fontspec' tag to your posting, as `polyglossia` automatically loads `fontspec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to set it in a different environment. Here are several examples. Note that I changed the English font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David}
    \newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily{\englishfontrm}{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily{\englishfontsf}{Linux Biolinum O}
    \newfontfamily{\englishfonttt}{Libertinus Mono}
    
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
    \begin{englishfontrm}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    \end{englishfontrm}

    \begin{englishfontsf}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    \end{englishfontsf}

    \begin{englishfonttt}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    \end{englishfonttt} 
\end{english}


\begin{hebrew}
לצערי ההרצאה בוטלה בגלל ה-
\begin{english}\englishfontrm{Corona}\end{english}. 

לצערי ההרצאה בוטלה בגלל ה-
\begin{english}\englishfontsf{Corona}\end{english}.

לצערי ההרצאה בוטלה בגלל ה-
\begin{english}\englishfonttt{Corona}\end{english}.
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with your example.

Comment: Upvote and accept if it works for you.

Comment: @AML Upvote for your answer, but you defined twice the roman font for English: once in `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{...}` and then in `\newfontfamily{\englishfontrm}{...}`. I don't see any reason for defining two different commands, `\englishfont` and `\englishfontrm` to insert English text in roman face, altogether when you use the same font face for both.